# django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: 'block' tag with name 'bottom_js' appears more than once

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-1.4

I have this error : `django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: 'block' tag with name 'bottom_js' appears more than once`

But I have no clue which template is at fault, how do I find this out ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 217, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 105, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 194, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 183, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 160, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbgettext/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    autodiscover()
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbgettext/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    app_path = import_module(app).__path__
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
    handle_registrations()
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/__init__.py", line 151, in handle_registrations
    search_sites_conf = importlib.import_module(settings.HAYSTACK_SITECONF)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/maazza/PycharmProjects/list_app/list_app/search_sites.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cms.models import monkeypatch_reverse
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    patch_settings()
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in patch_settings
    post_patch_check()
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/conf/patch.py", line 56, in post_patch_check
    if not validate_template(template[0], ['js', 'css']):
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sekizai/helpers.py", line 97, in validate_template
    found = get_namespaces(template)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sekizai/helpers.py", line 87, in get_namespaces
    compiled_template = get_template(template)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 145, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 134, in find_template
    source, display_name = loader(name, dirs)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 42, in __call__
    return self.load_template(template_name, template_dirs)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 48, in load_template
    template = get_template_from_string(source, origin, template_name)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 156, in get_template_from_string
    return Template(source, origin, name)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 125, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 153, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 267, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 214, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 267, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/home/maazza/.virtualenvs/list_app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 185, in do_block
    raise TemplateSyntaxError("'%s' tag with name '%s' appears more than once" % (bits[0], block_name))
django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: 'block' tag with name 'bottom_js' appears more than once
```

EDIT:
In a template I found this :

```
{% render_block "bottom_js" %}
{% block bottom_js %}
    <script>
     stufff
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Does it make a duplicate of the `bottom_js` block ?

Comment: Do you have `Debug=True` in your settings.py? You should get a stacktrace.

Comment: I have the stacktrace but it does not  mention the template name

Comment: It should post where it originates from. Could you post it, please?

Comment: Yes, that produces two blocks. It's from `Sekizai`. If you want to add to that block use the tags `{% addtoblock "bottom_js" %} {% endaddtoblock %}`.

Comment: ok , but it seems i need to check all the templates for it , damn

Comment: I would start here: `list_app/list_app/search_sites.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok fixed using a search in Pycharm and spotting 2 usages in the same File.
I hope there is way to find it out without PyCharm tough.

grep equivalent:

```
 grep -r -i "bottom_js" ./
```

taken from here : http://www.tonyspencer.com/2005/10/14/grep-all-files-and-sub-directories-in-a-directory-for-a-string/